# ASP.NET C# How to generate dynamic Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle

I'm using asp.net c# and I want to generate textbox from database. I have 4 records in my table so i want 4 textbox at run time.
But I'm getting only one textbox when checking in `Insepct Element` I get 4 textboxes but it does't show on my page.

Not sure where it went wrong.

I'm using code like this

```
OracleConnection obj_Conn = new OracleConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["OracleConn"].ToString());
    Table table = new Table();
    table.ID = "table1";
    string Query = "SELECT * FROM XXCUS.MASTER_VERIFICATION";
    OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(Query, obj_Conn);
    //DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
    var Count = dt.Rows.Count;
    if (Count > 0)
    {
        TableRow row = new TableRow();
        TextBox txt = new TextBox();
        for (int i = 0; i < Count; i++)
        {
            TableCell cell = new TableCell();
            txt.ID = "txt" + i.ToString();
            cell.ID = "cell" + i.ToString();

            cell.Controls.Add(txt);

            row.Cells.Add(cell);
        }
        table.Rows.Add(row);
        dvGenerateCntrl.Controls.Add(table);
    }
```

and call this method on Page Load

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First debug your code and make sure that you get 4 rows in your `datatable` and use this code.

```
    OracleConnection obj_Conn = new `OracleConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["oracleConn"].ToString());`
    Table table = new Table();
    table.ID = "table1";
    string Query = "SELECT * FROM XXCUS.MASTER_VERIFICATION";
    OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(Query, obj_Conn);
    //DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
    var Count = dt.Rows.Count;
    if (Count > 0)
    {
        TableRow row = new TableRow();
        TextBox txt = new TextBox();
        for (int i = 0; i < Count; i++)
        {
TextBox txt = new TextBox();            
TableCell cell = new TableCell();
            txt.ID = "txt" + i.ToString();
            cell.ID = "cell" + i.ToString();

            cell.Controls.Add(txt);

            row.Cells.Add(cell);
        }
        table.Rows.Add(row);
        dvGenerateCntrl.Controls.Add(table);
    }
```

In your code you don't create object of TextBox every time.
I think it will help you.

Answer (score 2):

put the line which declare a new `TextBox` inside of `for` loop

```
    for (int i = 0; i < Count; i++)
    {
        TextBox txt = new TextBox();
        TableCell cell = new TableCell();
        txt.ID = "txt" + i.ToString();
        cell.ID = "cell" + i.ToString();

        cell.Controls.Add(txt);

        row.Cells.Add(cell);
    }
```